# Deployed angular project 'GET' request not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express, http

I have an built angular project that I'm trying to run. I have copied the folder that I got from 'ng build' and put it in the folder where I have my back end code (used express). I'm running it on my laptop at port 3000.
While all the post requests in my application work fine, none of the GET requests seem to work.

[image: Here is the exact error I'm getting.]
Here is the exact error I'm getting.

If more information is needed to find out what I'm doing wrong, please ask.

Edit 1:
[image: Network Tab]

This is what I'm getting in the network tab. The response says html. But when I was working before deployment all my responses were coming as intended.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: the screenshot you added shows the responses coming back as 200/ok. this would imply that the service is correctly responding and it's not a network issue. do you have any logic that parses the response? and have you traced through to ensure there are no errors.
Also the error mentions a failure to parse the response. have you looked at the network tab to confirm the data you are getting is in fact valid JSON?

Comment: @Edward I've added an Edit 1 to my question in which I've added a screenshot of the network tab. As mentioned in the edit, I seem to have the problem only during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the images that you mentioned here, it look like that is has a http failure duing parsing in header:

Take a look here in order to resolve the same:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18396

Thanks